# dup2 function and program behaviour

Tags: c

if am writing a code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i;
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("shiv.txt","w");
  printf("%d",fileno(fp));
  dup2(3,1);
  fprintf(fp,"hello");  
}
```

as an output the program is printing `hello3` in the `shiv.txt` file

as we can see `printf` is called first yet its output is shown after the output of `fprintf`.

moreover `dup2` was called after the `printf` statement therefore the output of `printf` should be placed on terminal

Comment: Have you tried flushing the output before calling `dup2` i.e. `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Should 1st Argument to dup2 be file pointer, `fp`?  ***[reference](http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:dup2)***

Comment: @ryyker No the declaration of dup2 is `int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);`. It takes a file descriptor not a file pointer.

Comment: Of course, you have no guarantee that `fp` corresponds to file descriptor 3... In this simple case you may get away with it, but you should probably use `fileno(fp)` instead of hardcoding 3... If I ran your program as `foo 3< some_file.txt`, your `dup2(3,1)` would not do what you expect.

Comment: i know there is no guarantee that fp corresponds to file descriptor 3.
but i somehow know it.
or you can either replace it with dup2(fileno(fp),1)

Answer (score 2):

The standard I/O streams are buffered — with the possible exception of the standard error stream, which is only required to not be fully buffered by POSIX. Without a call to `fflush(stdout)` to flush the output buffer for standard output (or the output of a newline sequence if it is line-buffered), the way things work with respect to the `FILE` interface is not defined once you call `dup2`.

Since `dup2` works with file descriptors and not `FILE` pointers, you have a problem: POSIX doesn't specify what to do in this case. The buffer associated with `stdout` may be discarded, or it may be flushed as if with `fclose`. The buffer may even remain associated and not flushed/discarded since `stdout` from the perspective of the `FILE` interface is still open.

So the behavior isn't necessarily deterministic without syncing the `FILE` interface with the underlying file description (add an `fclose(stdout)` call after `dup2`). Additionally, what happens with, e.g., `stderr` in addition to `stdout` with `dup2` associated with the file description of the file you open? Is the behavior in order of the `dup2` calls as with a queue or in reverse order as with a stack or even in a seemingly random order, the latter of which suggests that a segfault may be possible? And what is the order of output if you `dup2(STDERR_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO)`, followed by `dup2(fileno(fp), STDERR_FILENO)`? Do the results of writing to the standard output/error buffers appear before the fprintf results or after or mixed (or sometimes one and sometimes another)? Which appears first — the data written to stderr or the data written to stdout? **Can you be certain this will always happen in that order?**

The answer probably won't surprise you: No. What happens on one configuration may differ from what happens on another configuration because the interaction between file descriptors, the buffers used by the standard streams, and the FILE interface of the standard streams is left undefined.

As @twalberg commented, there is no guarantee that the file you opened is file descriptor 3, so be careful when hard-coding numbers like that. Also, you have `STDOUT_FILENO` available from `<unistd.h>`, which is where `dup2` is actually declared, so you can avoid using a call to `fileno` in place of file descriptor 1 by using it.

Comment: i added fclose(fp) after fprintf but no changes.

Comment: i tried later as dup2(stderr_fileno,stdout_fileno) followed by dup2(fileno(fp),stderr_fileno)
this resulted in 3 on terminal and hello in file

Comment: @shivgarg The `fclose(fp)` already happens when the program exits. To see a change, add `fclose(stdout)` after `dup2(3, 1)`.

Comment: @shivgarg They were rhetorical questions used to convey my point: you cannot rely upon the order of the output beyond the dup2 call with the fprintf, printf, putchar, etc. functions because of the buffering used with stdout and possibly stderr. There isn't really any requirement for a specific behavior of the buffers associated with stdout, stderr, etc. when the corresponding file descriptors are dup2'd.

Answer (score 1):

There are rules to follow when manipulating "handles" to open file descriptions.

Per [System Interfaces Chapter 2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/xsh_chap02_05.html), file descriptors and streams are "handles" to file descriptions and a file description can have multiple handles.

This chapter defines rules when working with both a file descriptor and a stream for the same file description.  If they are not followed, then the results are "undefined".

Calling `dup2()` to replace the `stdout` file descriptor after calling `printf()` (on the `STDOUT` stream) without a call to `fflush(STDOUT)` in between is a violation of those rules (simplified), hence the undefined behavior.